# Shiny UI aesthetic improvements for table like user inputs

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, slider

I am creating a Shiny app where I'd like the user to select inputs in what looks like a table.  My code works, however it doesn't look very pretty as the slider bars do not line up with their associated information.  A few questions:

1. Is there any way to get the slider bars to line up with the associated text correctly?
2. All the inputs on the slider bars are the same, can I only display the labels on the one the user is currently hovering over?  Or perhaps just the top or bottom slider?
3. How do I force it so that the "table" doesn't resize/wrap itself when the window is minimised?

Screenshots showing the undesirable look of the "table" with slider bars not lining up correctly, and the "wrapped" look when the screen is minimised.

[image]
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Overall Title"),
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      h4(strong("Set lake N concentrations (ppb)")),
      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               h5(strong("Lake")),
               h5("Okareka"),
               h5("Tikitapu")
        ),
        column(3,
               h5(strong("Existing N")),
               h5("190.98"),
               h5("173.88")
        ),

        column(4,
               h5(strong("Improvement/Degradation")),
               sliderTextInput(
                 inputId = "DegImp_1",
                 label = "",
                 grid = TRUE,
                 force_edges = TRUE,
                 choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
                 selected = "No change"
               ),

               sliderTextInput(
                 inputId = "DegImp_8",
                 label = "",
                 grid = TRUE,
                 force_edges = TRUE,
                 choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
                 selected = "No change"
               )
        ),
        column(2,
               h5(strong("Value")),
               textOutput("DegImp_1value"),
               textOutput("DegImp_8value")
        )
      )
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

# server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  DI_1value <- reactive ({ switch(input$DegImp_1, "-20%" = 190.98*0.8, "-10%" = 190.98*0.9, "No change" = 190.98, "10%" = 190.98*1.1, "20%" = 190.98*1.2)})
  DI_8value <- reactive ({ switch(input$DegImp_8, "-20%" = 173.88*0.8, "-10%" = 173.88*0.9, "No change" = 173.88, "10%" = 173.88*1.1, "20%" = 173.88*1.2)})
  
  output$DegImp_1value <- renderPrint({ round(DI_1value(),2) })
  output$DegImp_8value <- renderPrint({ round(DI_8value(),2) })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed row-by-row with `splitLayout`. The result is not bad:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(

  splitLayout(
    h5(strong("Lake")),
    h5(strong("Existing N")),
    h5(strong("Improvement"))
  ),
  
  splitLayout(
    h5("Okareka"),
    h5(190.18),
    sliderTextInput(
      inputId = "DegImp_1",
      label = "",
      grid = TRUE,
      force_edges = TRUE,
      choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
      selected = "No change"
    )
  ),
  
  splitLayout(
    h5("Tikitapu"),
    h5(173.88),
    sliderTextInput(
      inputId = "DegImp_8",
      label = "",
      grid = TRUE,
      force_edges = TRUE,
      choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
      selected = "No change"
    )
  )
    
), 

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
})
```

Here is a more compact version:

[image]

```
fluidPage(

  div(
    style = "width: 500px;",
    
    splitLayout(
      h5(strong("Lake")),
      h5(strong("Existing N")),
      h5(strong("Improvement")),
      cellWidths = c("20%", "20%", "60%")
    ),
    
    splitLayout(
      h5("Okareka"),
      h5(190.18),
      sliderTextInput(
        inputId = "DegImp_1",
        label = "",
        grid = TRUE,
        force_edges = TRUE,
        choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
        selected = "No change",
        width = "200px"
      ),
      cellWidths = c("20%", "20%", "60%")
    ),
    
    splitLayout(
      h5("Tikitapu"),
      h5(173.88),
      sliderTextInput(
        inputId = "DegImp_8",
        label = "",
        grid = TRUE,
        force_edges = TRUE,
        choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
        selected = "No change",
        width = "200px"
      ),
      cellWidths = c("20%", "20%", "60%")
    )
  
  )
    
)
```

You can shift up the sliders by including them in a `div` with a negative top-margin:

[image]

```
splitLayout(
  h5("Okareka"),
  h5(190.18),
  div(
    style = "margin-top: -15px;",
    sliderTextInput(
      inputId = "DegImp_1",
      label = "",
      grid = TRUE,
      force_edges = TRUE,
      choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
      selected = "No change",
      width = "200px"
    )
  ),
  cellWidths = c("20%", "20%", "60%")
),

splitLayout(
  h5("Tikitapu"),
  h5(173.88),
  div(
    style = "margin-top: -15px;",
    sliderTextInput(
      inputId = "DegImp_8",
      label = "",
      grid = TRUE,
      force_edges = TRUE,
      choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
      selected = "No change",
      width = "200px"
    )
  ),
  cellWidths = c("20%", "20%", "60%")
)
```

Or, better, set `label = NULL`, not `label = ""`:

[image]

```
splitLayout(
  h5("Okareka"),
  h5(190.18),
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "DegImp_1",
    label = NULL,
    grid = TRUE,
    force_edges = TRUE,
    choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
    selected = "No change",
    width = "200px"
  ),
  cellWidths = c("20%", "20%", "60%")
),

splitLayout(
  h5("Tikitapu"),
  h5(173.88),
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "DegImp_8",
    label = NULL,
    grid = TRUE,
    force_edges = TRUE,
    choices = c("-20%", "-10%", "No change", "10%", "20%"),
    selected = "No change",
    width = "200px"
  ),
  cellWidths = c("20%", "20%", "60%")
)
```